# How to make MS account in windows phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, microsoft-account

I'm very very new with windows phone. I just want to know how to create new Microsoft account in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/accounts-and-billing/create-a-microsoft-account), I have given the steps below:

> - To create a Microsoft account when you set up your phone
>
>   Follow the setup instructions on your phone until you get to the **Keep your life in sync** screen.
>
>   1. Tap **Create one**, then follow the instructions.
>   2. Once you've finished this step, you'll be signed in to your phone.
> - To create an account after your phone is set up
>
>   1. In the App list, tap **Settings** > **Email + accounts**.
>   2. Tap **Add an account** > **Microsoft account**.
>   3. On the **Keep your life in sync** screen, tap **Create one**, and follow the instructions to set up the account.
>
> Once you've finished this step, you'll be signed in to your phone.
>
> ***To create a Microsoft account from the Web***
>
> To create a Microsoft account from a web browser, go to the [Microsoft account sign-in website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=330442) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score -2):

Simply go to www.microsoft.com and tap at the upper right corner the option sign in
Then tap "I dont have a ......."
Follow the steps

Comment: The question is about creating a new account on the phone, not on Microsoft's website.